# Клонирование строк 2D матрицы в Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Передо мной стоит задача из данного массива

```
np.array([[1, 2], 
          [2, 3], 
          [3, 4])
```

получить следующий:

```
np.array([[1, 2], 
          [1, 2], 
          [2, 3], 
          [2, 3], 
          [3, 4], 
          [3, 4]])
```

Короче говоря: продублировать каждый элемент массива.

Понимаю, что это выполняется с помощью **np.tile()**, но конкретно с этим примером не могу справиться.

Буду благодарна за помощь!

Comment: чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

здесь лучше подойдет [np.repeat()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
In [58]: np.repeat(a, 2, axis=0)
Out[58]:
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```

можно это сделать и при помощи [np.tile()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html), но это будет выглядеть более коряво:

```
In [59]: np.tile(a, 2).reshape(-1, a.shape[-1])
Out[59]:
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```